# Select the first element from a drop down with dynamically changing values Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

[Image of Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43F1i.png)

Description - Select the first element from the drop down on "Available Slots". The values of the drop down keeps changing. I am not able to select the first value. I am able do upto clicking on the drop down to see the elements using selenium. I am stuck there

Few observations -

- The IDs for the li tags keep changing.
- There is a ul li section on the code with the slots and also below there is "select" tag with multiple "option" tags with the available slots. I am confused as to which specific webelement's xpath I have to use.

Here below is the entire html code for the section I am working on. What can I do to select the first element from the dropdown.

```
<div class="select-wrapper"><input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-d78257d9-b2fd-a3cd-1678-8db6a678a01e">**<ul id="select-options-d78257d9-b2fd-a3cd-1678-8db6a678a01e" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 184.85px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 108px; transform-origin: 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);"><li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-d78257d9-b2fd-a3cd-1678-8db6a678a01e0" tabindex="0"><span>Select Slot</span></li><li id="select-options-d78257d9-b2fd-a3cd-1678-8db6a678a01e1" tabindex="0"><span>12pm-3pm</span></li><li id="select-options-d78257d9-b2fd-a3cd-1678-8db6a678a01e2" tabindex="0"><span>3pm-6pm</span></li></ul>**<svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg><select name="id_slot" required="" tabindex="-1"><option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Slot</option><option value="2">12pm-3pm</option><option value="3">3pm-6pm</option></select></div>
```

PS - All Ids are dynamically changing, so can't use that as an identifier

Few tries I have done and failed -

- Used Action Chains to send the down arrow. Manually when I do it, if I just press the down arrow and enter, it will select the option I want. Maybe we could simulate Down then Enter. But not working - It doesn't move to the option I want

body = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='schedule_modal']/form/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/select")
body.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

- Tried using the select tag by value and index. I get this error

select = Select(driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='schedule_modal']/form/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/select"))
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
select.select_by_value('1')

```
Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.